How does salicylic acid ingestion affect insect metabolism?
It is well known that plants may use salicylic acid as a signalling hormone when under attack by certain phytophagous insects.
Moreover, exogenous salicylic acid admixing with insecticides seems to synergistically potentiate these insecticides.
One would suspect that this effect is caused by salicylic acid ingestion by the herbivore parasites on top of improved hormone signalling within the plant. However, almost all articles I read about this subject focus on crop yield, with one exception.
Hence, my question: How does salicylic acid ingestion affect insect metabolism? I am especially interested in the effects on members of the suborder Sternorrhyncha.
Any links to a good review article would also be well appreciated.
